# Store the return of a function in variable

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm learning python, and I'm having trouble saving the return of a function to a specific variable. I have computed a simple function 'average' that is supposed to return the average value of a list. This works fine, however, when I try to store the result of average in a variable, I get told that x isn't defined.

```
def average(x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)

var=average(x)
```

How do I store the return of the function in a variable?

Edit:
I misunderstood the task, which was simply to store the results of a specific computation in a variable.

Comment: Well, where was `x` supposed to come from?  You have to have something in order to find the average of it!

Comment: I think you need add 'x=[1, 2, 3]', i.e. assign x a value

Comment: I want to store the output of the function in a variable. Such that if I write average([1,3,5]), var will equal to 3.

Answer (score 0):

`x` indeed is not defined

```
def average(x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)

x = [1,2,3] # this was missing

var=average(x)
```

https://repl.it/join/eldrjqcr-datamafia

Answer (score 0):

The function is a black box. You made the black box expect one mandatory input (`x`), therefore you have to provide it first i.e. `var = average([1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score -1):

Read the error message, x isn't defined. The variable x exists only in the average function and not in the program. You need to set x to something first.
e.g.

```
def average(x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)
x=[1,2,3]
var=average(x)
```

this will not cause an error

Comment: Can I define x as a list? I need x to store the return of the function without needing input.

Comment: you could define x do be whatever you want, but it needs to be a list or it will cause another error